# Spark BigQuery Connector Error getting access token from metadata server

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am getting this error while trying to write to BigQuery using spark bigquery connector. The application is run from a hadoop cluster (not dataproc).

java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:236)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialConfiguration.getCredential(CredentialConfiguration.java:91)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getCredential(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1533)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1554)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:654)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:617)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:62)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:42)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)

Here is the code,

```
    dataset.write().format("bigquery")
            .option("temporaryGcsBucket", tempGcsBucket)
            //.option("table", databaseName + "." + tableName)
            .option("project", projectId)
            .option("parentProject", parentProjectId)
            .option("credentials", credentials)
            .mode(saveMode).save(projectId + "." + databaseName + "." + tableName);
```

I am able to read from the same table that I am trying to write to, using the same credentials (service account base 64 encoded). I am  using spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11-0.19.1.jar version of connector.

The same code worked fine in our lower environment where the project and parent project are same. But in prod, they are different.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue?  Can you please share your solutioin

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to deal with this issue by modifying code from [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/224)
First you need configure your spark session

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.project.id", <project_id>)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.system.bucket", <bucket>)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", <client_email>)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id", <private_key_id>)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key", <private_key>)
```

Then you need to convert your key JSON to base 64. I used this simple helper

```
def to_base64(creds):
    creds_bytes = creds.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(creds_bytes)
    return base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
```

And then write your data

```
(dataFrame
 .write
 .format("bigquery")
 .mode("append")
 .option("credentials", to_base64(<creds>))
 .option("parentProject", <project_id>)
 .option("temporaryGcsBucket", <bucket>)
 .option("table", <table_name>)
 .save()
)
```

I'm not quite sure if you need all of these hadoopConfiguration options but at least it worked for me.